# Specifying the lambda return type in Scala

Tags: scala, types, lambda

*Note: this is a theoretical question, I am not trying to fix anything, nor am I trying to achieve any effect for a practical purpose*

When creating a lambda in Scala using the `(arguments)=>expression` syntax, can the return type be explicitly provided?

Lambdas are no different than methods on that they both are specified as expressions, but as far as I understand it, the return type of methods is defined easily with the `def name(arguments): return type = expression` syntax.

Consider this (illustrative) example:

```
def sequence(start: Int, next: Int=>Int): ()=>Int = {
    var x: Int = start

    //How can I denote that this function should return an integer?    
    () => {
        var result: Int = x
        x = next(x)
        result
    }
}
```

Comment: You have already done that by specifying `() => Int` as `sequence`'s return type. This already enforces that the lambda that you return must conform to that type and the compiler will try to interpret it as such.

Comment: @ghik It's just an unfortunate example...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can always declare the type of an expression by appending `:` and the type.  So, for instance:

```
((x: Int) => x.toString): (Int => String)
```

This is useful if you, for instance, have a big complicated expression and you don't want to rely upon type inference to get the types straight.

```
{
  if (foo(y)) x => Some(bar(x))
  else        x => None
}: (Int => Option[Bar])
// Without type ascription, need (x: Int)
```

But it's probably even clearer if you assign the result to a temporary variable with a specified type:

```
val fn: Int => Option[Bar] = {
  if (foo(y)) x => Some(bar(x))
  else        _ => None
}
```

Comment: That seems to be what I was looking for! However: is that a compile-time check or a cast?

Comment: @yannbane That is a compile-time check, not a cast.

Comment: In Scala in order to make any function recursive we need to specify a return type, and as of 2020.2.3, IntelliJ will not be able to auto-suggest a return type so this answer is actually important for Scala coder to understand.

Answer (score 3):

```
x => x:SomeType
```

Did not know the answer myself as I never had the need for it, but my gut feeling was that this will work. And trying it in a worksheet confirmed it.

Edit: I provided this answer before there was an example above. It is true that this is not needed in the concrete example. But in rare cases where you'd need it, the syntax I showed will work.

Comment: *Ahem, could you use that in a sentence?* Joking aside, please see my edit. I'm new to Scala so I don't quite understand how to integrate your answer.

Comment: In your example you would not need to specify that it is an Int. Because Int is already the type inferred by the compiler. Why would you want to specify it explicitly here? You could (writing `result:Int`), but it would not make any difference.

Comment: Yeah yeah, I picked an unfortunate example. But let's just pretend it's a random lambda in the middle of nothing, not being returned or anything...

Comment: In TypeScript that's how we'd do it, but in Scala, this will not work, you will need to specify the type as a function that returns a value as in the above accepted answer, or it will not compile.

Answer (score 3):

Let say you have this function:

```
def mulF(a: Int, b: Int): Long = {
      a.toLong * b
}
```

The same function can be written as lambda with defined input and output types:

```
val mulLambda: (Int, Int) => Long = (x: Int, y: Int) => { x.toLong * y }
```