# Define return value in Spark Scala UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, udf

Imagine the following code:

```
def myUdf(arg: Int) = udf((vector: MyData) => {
  // complex logic that returns a Double
})
```

How can I define the return type for myUdf so that people looking at the code will know immediately that it returns a Double?

Comment: Have you thought about accepting an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spark [functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) define several `udf` methods that have the following modifier/type: `static <RT,A1, ..., A10> UserDefinedFunction`

You can specify the input/output data types in square brackets as follows:

```
def myUdf(arg: Int) = udf[Double, MyData]((vector: MyData) => {
  // complex logic that returns a Double
})
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to compile.

Comment: Defining `MyData` (or returning some random `Double`) is out of scope

Answer (score 6):

I see two ways to do it, either define a method first and then lift it to a function

```
def myMethod(vector:MyData) : Double = {
  // complex logic that returns a Double
}

val myUdf = udf(myMethod _)
```

or define a function first with explicit type:

```
val myFunction: Function1[MyData,Double] = (vector:MyData) => {
  // complex logic that returns a Double
}

val myUdf = udf(myFunction)
```

I normally use the firt approach for my UDFs

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a type parameter to `udf` but you need to seemingly counter-intuitively pass the return type first, followed by the input types like `[ReturnType, ArgTypes...]`, at least as of Spark 2.3.x. Using the original example (*which seems to be a curried function based on `arg`*):

```
def myUdf(arg: Int) = udf[Double, Seq[Int]]((vector: Seq[Int]) => {
  13.37 // whatever
})
```

Comment: This is copy/paste of my answer that you are well aware of.

Comment: Oh I guess I just didn't properly see your self-answer since it was listed at the bottom! Honestly wasn't a copy paste, we just wrote the same thing / with different comment :) Anyway the _misleading_ compiler/IDE error "Undefined type parameters" which led to my comment are in fact not related to input type - but return type of the function - it will be the error as long as the body returns Unit. I'll update my answer to help other readers.

Comment: And I just realized that I answered my own question and later accepted it... Not sure if I was looking for badges or just burnt out!

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about UDF with lambda functions, they behave just like scala lambda function (see [Specifying the lambda return type in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313194/specifying-the-lambda-return-type-in-scala)) so you could do:

```
def myUdf(arg: Int) = udf(((vector: MyData) => {
  // complex logic that returns a Double
}): (MyData => Double))
```

or instead explicitly define your function:

```
def myFuncWithArg(arg: Int) {
  def myFunc(vector: MyData): Double = {
     // complex logic that returns a Double. Use arg here
  }
  myFunc _
}

def myUdf(arg: Int) = udf(myFuncWithArg(arg))
```

Comment: how do I use 'arg' in the second example?